# Add custom field as an order note in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, user-roles

I'm trying to add a custom field `jckwds_date` as an order note. I can't for the life of me figure out why this code isn't working in `functions.php`?

The code also only allows the note to be added in the are a certain role type.

```
function wdm_my_custom_notes_on_single_order_page($order){

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $allowed_roles = array('eu_no_vat', 'super_wholesale_customer', 'wholesale_customer');

    if( array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) )  {

        $value = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'jckwds_date', true );

        echo $value;

        $order->add_order_note( $value, $is_customer_note = 1 );

    }
}
```

Basically I need [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4UWS.png):

[image: THIS]

To be added [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atYxY.png):

[image: HERE]

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

The following code will add from the order custom field 'jckwds_date' (or checkout posted field value 'jckwds_date') an order note that will appear in backend for defined user roles:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'product_custom_field_to_custom_order_notes', 100, 2 );
function product_custom_field_to_custom_order_notes( $order_id, $data ){
    // HERE define allowed user roles
    $allowed_roles = array('administrator', 'super_wholesale_customer', 'wholesale_customer');

    $user_id = get_post_meta( '_customer_user', 'jckwds_date', true );
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

    // Exit if no matched user roles
    if( ! array_intersect( $allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) return;

    // Get the date custom field (or checkout field)
    if( get_post_meta( $order_id, 'jckwds_date', true ) ){
        $note = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'jckwds_date', true );
    } elseif( isset( $_POST['jckwds_date'] ) ){
        $note = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['jckwds_date'] );
    }

    // The order note
    if( isset($note) && ! empty($note) ){
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // The WC_Order Object
        $order->add_order_note( $note );  // Add the note
        $order->save(); // Save the order
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately it didn't work when I just tested it :/

Comment: @Tommy Is your custom field a product custom field?

Comment: It's an order custom field, it's basically a date that they choose for delivery during checkout.

Comment: @Tommy  This is different then… **I have updated my answer code** and I hope it will work.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I tried it, it's not working for me . Should the note still be added even the order is failed status?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_add_checkout_fields' );
// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_add_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
     $fields['order']['order_note']['priority'] = 5;
     $fields['order']['order_note'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Order Notes', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Order Notes', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );  
     return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the custom field has already been added and showing during checkout. It's just adding it to the notes when the customer places an order.

Comment: is it a private note or note to a customer?

Comment: Private note mate

Comment: You can take reference from the below url 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667381/add-a-custom-order-note-programmatically-in-woocommerce-admin-order-edit-pages

Comment: Hey, I have tried that and I can get it to print plain text but can't get it to pull through the custom field value in to the note.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$order = wc_get_order(  $order_id );


$note = __("This my custom note...");


$order->add_order_note( $note );

$order->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I need to display the actual custom field value, not just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'checkout_field_update_order_meta');

                    function checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id)
                    {
                        if (!empty($_POST['field_name'])) {
                            update_post_meta($order_id, 'MY Custom Field', sanitize_text_field($_POST['field_name']));
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Hi, I don't see where it updates the notes? Just the order meta. The custom fields are working fine on the front end and saving in the back-end it's just adding them as a private note once they place the order.

Comment: @Tommy You mean just add the custom private note after customer place the order?. It's only visible in admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_note_custom' );

    function my_note_custom( $order_id ) {

          $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
          $note = __("This my custom note...");
          $order->add_order_note( $note );

          $order->save();

    }
```

Comment: Hi, I don't see where it updates the notes? Just the order meta. The custom fields are working fine on the front end and saving in the back-end it's just adding them as a private note once they place the order.

Comment: @Tommy , have you found a way to send the cistom field as a private note?

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was a simple as changing the `$product` to `$order` as it is the order custom field value I'm trying to retrieve.

Full code below:

```
function wdm_my_custom_notes_on_single_order_page($order){

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $allowed_roles = array('eu_no_vat', 'super_wholesale_customer', 'wholesale_customer');

    if( array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) )  {

        $value = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'jckwds_date', true );

        $note = '<b>Wholesale</b>';

        echo $value;

        $order->add_order_note( $value, $is_customer_note = 1 );

    }
}
```