# Set default order comments based on cart total in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I want to add a default order comment (or pre populate the `order_comments` field) if the cart total is over 25 euros.

I already found this post about it: [Add a custom order note programmatically in Woocommerce admin order edit pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667381/add-a-custom-order-note-programmatically-in-woocommerce-admin-order-edit-pages)

---

I almost got it working:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'set_default_order_comment' );
function set_default_order_comment( $order, $fields ) {
    // Targeting My account section
    if ( $order->get_total() > 25 ) {
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['default'] = 'Custom note!!';
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

At least, I think this should be it, but not quite right yet. I got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function

How can create a simple function that checks the total amount in cart and if it is over 25 euro automaticly add an default order comment to the order?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this.

```php
/**
 * Add a custom note when the order total is above 25.
 *
 * @param int      $order_id Order ID.
 * @param WC_Order $order    Order object.
 */
function vkh_woocommerce_new_order_action( $order_id, $order ) {
    if ( $order->get_total() > 25 ) {
        $note = __( 'Write your note here!' );

        // Add the note
        $order->add_order_note( $note );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'vkh_woocommerce_new_order_action', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thank you for this. This is working but I think I asked the question wrong. I need this to be in de customer order notes. In the checkout sometimes customers can leave a not. I want to add this note automaticly with a function. Is this possible the same way you did this?

Comment: You can pass 2nd and 3rd value in function `add_order_note` as true/false. You can read about it in detail here https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/WC_Order::add_order_note

Answer (score 0):

The error is there because `$order` is not an argument of the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter hook, you should use `get_cart_contents_total()` instead

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // Get cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();

    // Greater than
    if ( $cart_total > 25 ) { 
        $fields['order']['order_comments']['default'] = __( 'Custom note!', 'woocommerce' );
    }   

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'filter_woocommerce_checkout_fields', 10, 1 );
```